# Sample loss in Android app when retrieving data via BLE

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an Android app which retrieves data via BLE from a device in real-time.

As stated in the device's datasheet, BLE uses a 20-ms connection interval. Twenty user-data bytes (which is equal to 2- samples for each channel and 2-bytes running counter) are sent in GATT notifications. Data from the device is ping-pong buffered and up to six BLE-notification packets are sent every 14 ms based on an OSAL timer. The sample rate is set as 160 samples/sec. Each sample is 3 bytes and is sending 3 channels.

Each notification packet consists of 20 bytes containing the following:

Measurement Sample1 (Raw ADC data)

- Channel1 (3 bytes)
- Channel2 (3 bytes)
- Channel3 (3 bytes)

Measurement Sample 2 (Raw ADC data)

- Channel1 (3 bytes)
- Channel2 (3 bytes)
- Channel3 (3 bytes)

Afterwards I plot this data, but it looks like that I am only getting a sample rate around 105, while there should be 160 samples/sec. It just looks like some samples are missing looking from the signal.

I'm posting a code that I use below. I was wondering what could be the cause for that, is there a bug or a design flaw in the code? Are there any alternative methods to retrieve the data?

```
// This is used to register and get callback methods from Bluetooth adapter
 private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            String intentAction;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                        mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            }
        }

        //This method gets triggered auto whenever characteristics  is read by BT
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                         int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {

            //on successful read of value, call update function.
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
                Log.d("SOURCE", "charactersitics read");
            }
            Log.d("SOURCE", "error reading: " + Integer.toString(status));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    };

    Intent Sampintent;
    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                                 final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {


        if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {

            Sampintent = new Intent(action);
            final byte[] sigbytes = characteristic.getValue();
            Message m = Message.obtain();
            Bundle b =new Bundle();
            b.putByteArray("bytes",sigbytes);
            m.setData(b);
            mHandler.sendMessage(m);

        }
    }

    // handler object used to post process the sample read.
    private PostSampleRead mHandler = new PostSampleRead();
    public  class PostSampleRead extends Handler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            try {

            //raw byte array read at a time by BT. rouhgly 20 bytes per packet
                final byte[] b = msg.getData().getByteArray("bytes");

                // ignoring first two bytes b[0] and b[1] , contain running counter


                int b1 = b[2] & 0xff;
                int b2 = b[3] & 0xff;
                int b3 = b[4] & 0xff;


                if (b1 == 255 && b1 == b2 && b2 == b3) {
                } else {

                    // First sample of ch1
                    byte[] channel1 = {b[2], b[3], b[4]};

                    // First sample of ch2
                    byte[] channel2 = {b[5], b[6], b[7]};

                    // First sample of ch3
                    byte[] channel3 = {b[8], b[9], b[10]};


                    //pack three bytes to one value
                    BigInteger ch1 = new BigInteger(channel1);
                    BigInteger ch2 = new BigInteger(channel2);
                    BigInteger ch3 = new BigInteger(channel3);


                    String c1 = ch1.toString();
                    String c2 = ch2.toString();
                    String c3 = ch3.toString();

                    try {

                    //sneding all three samples to activity via broadcast.
                        Sampintent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA_CH1, c1);
                        Sampintent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA_CH2, c2);
                        Sampintent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA_CH3, c3);
                        sendBroadcast(Sampintent);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    // Second sample of ch1
                    byte[] channel1_ = {b[11], b[12], b[13]};

                    // Second sample of ch2
                    byte[] channel2_ = {b[14], b[15], b[16]};

                    // Second sample of ch3
                    byte[] channel3_ = {b[17], b[18], b[19]};


                    packing 3bytes into one value.
                    BigInteger ch1_ = new BigInteger(channel1_);
                    BigInteger ch2_ = new BigInteger(channel2_);
                    BigInteger ch3_ = new BigInteger(channel3_);

                    String c1_ = ch1_.toString();
                    String c2_ = ch2_.toString();
                    String c3_ = ch3_.toString();


                    sending to activity via broadcast.
                    Sampintent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA_CH1, c1_);
                    Sampintent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA_CH2, c2_);
                    Sampintent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA_CH3, c3_);
                    sendBroadcast(Sampintent);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    }
```